Enum into own file in mql5
i want use own enum file (enum.ex5) into (middle.ex5) and (last.ex5).
i can use #include instead of #import but i want use #import.
for exmaple :
- enum file "enum.ex5"
(i dont like use this file into #include)
enum ENUM_VALUE
{
   VAL_1,
   VAL_2,
   VAL_3,
};

- middle file "middle.ex5"
#property library

ENUM_VALUE test (bool access) export
{
   if (access == true)
      return VAL_1;
   else if (access == false)
      return VAL_2;

   return VAL_3;
}


- last file "last.ex5"
#import "middle.ex5"
   ENUM_VALUE test (bool access);
#import


thanks.

#import in MQL45 is used to import methods (functions) from compiled libraries (dll, native ex5, c#). It is not used to import classes, enums and interfaces.
So you have to use #include
